# Subalgebras of finite extensions

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

Suppose that $A\subset B$ is a finite extension of rings. Is it true that every intermediate extension $A\subset C\subset B$ finite over $A$?

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed to me by Thibault Poiret, the answer is no.  Take $A=k[x_1,x_2,\ldots]$ and $B=A[t]/t^2$. Then $B$ is clearly finite over $A$. Now take $C=A[tx_1,tx_2,\ldots]$.